# Unity Custom WebGL Templates - custom variables cause build errors

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

[Unity's documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-templates.html) states that custom user variables can be added to custom WebGL templates and then set in the Unity Editor. While I can access the variables in the list of existing variables, when I add custom variables, they do not appear in Project Settings > Player > Resolution and Presentation after reseleting template or reimporting. Of note, the image shown in Unity documentation also doesn't show any changes to the Editor window.

When attempting to build, however, Unity clearly is recognizing the variable. It throws a build error:

```
Building Builds\WebGL\index.html failed with output:

C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.12f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Preprocess.js:67
    throw "Preprocessor error \"" + e + "\" occured in file \"" + locals.inputPath + "\" when evaluating expression \"" + expression + "\"";
    ^
Preprocessor error "ReferenceError: ANOTHER_VARIABLE is not defined" occured in file "C:/.../Assets/WebGLTemplates/development/index.html" when evaluating expression " ANOTHER_VARIABLE "
(Use `node --trace-uncaught ...` to show where the exception was thrown)
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallGlobalEventHandler ()
```

Sample index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>{{{ PRODUCT_NAME }}} is cool</title>


</head>

<body>
    <div id="unity-container" class="unity-desktop">
        <canvas id="unity-canvas" width=960 height=600></canvas>
        <div id="unity-loading-bar">
            <img id="unity-logo" alt="Created by EY Client Technology's Metaverse Lab" />
            <div id="unity-progress-bar-empty">
                <div id="unity-progress-bar-full"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="unity-warning"> </div>
        <div id="unity-footer" style="display:none">
            <div id="unity-webgl-logo"></div>
            <div id="unity-fullscreen-button"></div>
            <div id="unity-build-title">Spraoi</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>


<script>

    console.log({{{ ANOTHER_VARIABLE }}});

    ....

</script>
```

`{{{ PRODUCT_NAME }}}` on it's own works fine. Adding `{{{ ANOTHER_VARIABLE }}}` causes a build error, but doesn't update Unity Editor

Answer (score 0):

Unity 2021.3.12

1. Restart Unity (may require multiple reboots)
2. The variables will appear, but the values you set may reset randomly so check them often